# Get the status of a v-checkbox Vue.JS Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm building a group of v-checkboxes

```
              <div class="row form-group" v-for="(author, key) in authorData" :key="key">

                <v-checkbox
                    label
                    :key="author.PmPubsAuthorID"
                    v-model="author.checked"
                    v-bind:id="author.PmPubsAuthorID.toString()"
                    color="success"
                    @change="authorCBClicked()"
                  ></v-checkbox>
```

How can I determine the status of the checkbox checked or unchecked?  I've Googled and have not found the answer. I don't want to use the dom object and would like to stay with Vue structure.

I've tried

```
      @change="authorCBClicked(key)"
```

but that did not help.  As you can tell I'm a Vue new users so any help is very much appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind in this way `v-model="authorData[key].checked"` and use @input event like:

```
<div class="row form-group" v-for="(author, key) in authorData" :key="key">

                <v-checkbox
                    label
                    :key="author.PmPubsAuthorID"
                    v-model="authorData[key].checked"
                    v-bind:id="author.PmPubsAuthorID.toString()"
                    color="success"
                    @change="authorCBClicked(authorData[key])"
                  ></v-checkbox>
```

Comment: the input would never fire the authorCBClicked so I changed it back to change and also change back to passing author so I can get other properties on the change such as the id of the checkbox.  How else would I get the other properties?  Thanks for the input

Comment: did you try ` @change="authorCBClicked(authorData[key])"`

Comment: ` @change="authorCBClicked(authorData[key])"`  worked great--

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox is v-binded, so `author.checked` should reflect the value set by the user.

Comment: In the authorCBClicked I get "author is not defined"  Do I need to past something with the @change?

Comment: Got it-- I passed author into the function @change="authorCBClicked(author)"  and that worked--Thanks

Comment: and inside the method you can check if `checked` is true or false :)